# Rails Association returns join model not actual model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So the join table is setup like this

User model.
Book model.

read_books is associating those two.

want_to_read_books is association those two again for a different reason.

Two join tables.

read_books

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
```

want_to_read_books

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
```

In the user table i have

```
has_many :books, through: :read_books
has_many :books, through: :want_to_read_books
```

in the book table I have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :read_books
has_and_belongs_to_many :want_to_read_books
```

To this point it all works fine BUT i am forced to reference them as:

```
user.read_books.first.book.title
```

instead of

```
user.read_books.first.title.
```

What do I need to add to make it return the model not the association?

I have also tried the following thinking it was what i was missing but resulted in the same thing.

```
has_many :books, through: :read_books
has_many :read_books

has_many :books, through: :want_to_read_books
has_many :want_to_read_books
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define several associations with the same name the methods defined by the later will just overwrite the previous association. Instead you want to just name your associations appropriately:

```
class User
  has_many :book_readings # for lack of a better name
  has_many :read_books, 
           through: :book_readings, 
           source: :book
  has_many :wishlist_books
  has_many :want_to_read_books, 
           through: :wishlist_books,
           source: :book
end

class BookReading
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end

class WishlistBook
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
end
```

Comment: is the last has_many through: supposed to say wishlist_books?

Comment: Yes, copypasta got me. Edited.